# Class can't be used in WCF service, while derived class can

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have an abstract class `FileFolderBase` with 2 classes deriving from it `File` and `Folder`, the class `ProjectFolder` is again deriving from the `Folder` class.

I have a WCF service, called `BrowseService` with 2 functions: `GetRoot`, which returns a list of  `ProjectFolder` instances, and `OpenFolder`, which returns one `Folder` instance.

Here's the service code

**iBrowseService.vb:**

```
Imports System.ServiceModel

<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IBrowseService

    <OperationContract()>
    Function OpenFolder(ByVal path As String) As Domain.Folder
    <OperationContract()>
    Function GetRoot(ByVal projectCodes As String) As List(Of Domain.ProjectFolder)
End Interface
```

**BrowseService.svc.vb:**

```
Imports System.ServiceModel.Activation

<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
Public Class BrowseService
    Implements IBrowseService

    Public Function OpenFolder(ByVal path As String) As Domain.Folder Implements IBrowseService.OpenFolder
        Dim service As MyService = New MyService()
        Dim folder As Domain.Folder = service.OpenFolder(path)
        Return folder
    End Function

    Public Function GetRoot(ByVal projectCodes As String) As List(Of Domain.ProjectFolder) Implements IBrowseService.GetRoot
        Dim service As MyService = New MyService()
        Dim folders As List(Of Domain.ProjectFolder)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(projectCodes) Then
            Dim codes As List(Of String) = projectCodes.Split(",").ToList
            folders = service.GetRoot(codes)
        Else
            folders = service.GetRoot(Nothing)
        End If
        Return folders
    End Function    
End Class
```

Nothing overly complicated there, now the odd thing is, the `GetRoot` function works perfectly and returns a set of `ProjectFolder` instances when I call it. The `OpenFolder` function however, won't work at all. The WCF test client gives a *'This operation is not supported in the WCF Test Client cause it uses the type Folder'* message and when I use the service in an application, I get a `CommunicationsException`, most inner exception message *'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host*', when invoking it.

I can't find any cause why `ProjectFolder` can be used, while `Folder` can't, especially cause `ProjectFolder` derives from `Folder`.

Here are the sources for the 4 type classes:

**FileFolderBase**

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

<Serializable()>
<DataContract(IsReference:=True)>
Public MustInherit Class FileFolderBase
    Implements IComparable(Of FileFolderBase)
#Region "Attributes"
    Protected varPkey As Long
    Protected varName As String
    Protected varFullName As String
    Protected varProjectFolder As ProjectFolder
    Protected varLastModified As Date
#End Region
#Region "Properties"
    <DataMember>
    Public Property Pkey() As Long
        Get
            Return varPkey
        End Get
        Set(value As Long)
            varPkey = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember>
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return varName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            varName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember>
    Public Property FullName() As String
        Get
            Return varFullName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            varFullName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember>
    Public Property ProjectFolder() As ProjectFolder
        Get
            Return varProjectFolder
        End Get
        Set(value As ProjectFolder)
            varProjectFolder = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember>
    Public Property LastModified() As Date
        Get
            Return Me.varLastModified
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Date)
            Me.varLastModified = value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region
#Region "Methods"
    'Equals function and = and <> operators
#End Region
#Region "CompareMethods"
'Comparison functions, used for sorting and stuff
#End Region
End Class
```

**File**

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

<Serializable()>
<DataContract(IsReference:=True)>
Public Class File
    Inherits FileFolderBase
#Region "Attributes"
    Private varSize As Long
    Private varComment As String
#End Region
#Region "Constructors"
    Public Sub New()
        Me.varPkey = 0
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal pkey As Long, ByVal name As String, ByVal fullName As String, ByVal lastModified As Date, ByVal size As Long, ByVal comment As String, ByVal project As ProjectFolder)
        Me.varPkey = pkey
        Me.varName = name
        Me.varFullName = fullName
        Me.varLastModified = lastModified
        Me.varSize = size
        Me.varComment = comment
        Me.varProjectFolder = project
    End Sub
#End Region
#Region "Properties"
    <DataMember>
    Public Property Size() As Long
        Get
            Return Me.varSize
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Long)
            Me.varSize = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember>
    Public Property Comment() As String
        Get
            Return Me.varComment
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.varComment = value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region
#Region "Methods"
    'Equals function and = and <> operators
#End Region
#Region "CompareMethods"
    'Comparison functions, used for sorting and stuff
#End Region
End Class
```

**Folder**

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
<Serializable()>
<DataContract(IsReference:=True)>
Public Class Folder
    Inherits FileFolderBase
#Region "Attributes"
    Protected varItems As List(Of FileFolderBase)
    Protected varParent As Folder
#End Region
#Region "Constructors"
    Public Sub New()
        Me.varPkey = 0
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal pkey As Long, ByVal name As String, ByVal fullName As String, ByVal lastModified As Date, ByVal parent As Folder, ByVal project As ProjectFolder)
        Me.varPkey = pkey
        Me.varName = name
        Me.varFullName = fullName
        Me.varLastModified = lastModified
        Me.varParent = parent
        Me.varProjectFolder = project
        varItems = New List(Of FileFolderBase)()
    End Sub
#End Region
#Region "Properties"
    <DataMember>
    Public Property Items() As List(Of FileFolderBase)
        Get
            Return Me.varItems
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of FileFolderBase))
            Me.varItems = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember>
    Public Property Parent() As Folder
        Get
            Return varParent
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Folder)
            Me.varParent = value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region
#Region "Methods"
    'Equals function and = and <> operators
#End Region
End Class
```

**ProjectFolder**

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

<Serializable()>
<DataContract(IsReference:=True)>
Public Class ProjectFolder
    Inherits Folder
#Region "Attributes"
    Private varProject As Project
#End Region
#Region "Constructors"
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal project As Project, ByVal parent As Folder)
        MyBase.New(0, project.Name, project.Name, Date.Now, parent, Nothing)
        Me.varProject = project
    End Sub
#End Region
#Region "Properties"
    <DataMember>
    Public Property Project() As Project
        Get
            Return Me.varProject
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Project)
            Me.varProject = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember>
    Public Overloads Property Items() As List(Of FileFolderBase)
        Get
            Return Me.varItems
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of FileFolderBase))
            Me.varItems = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember>
    Public Overloads Property ProjectFolder() As ProjectFolder
        Get
            Return Me
        End Get
        Set(value As ProjectFolder)

        End Set
    End Property
#End Region
#Region "Methods"
    'Equals function and = and <> operators
#End Region
End Class
```

Please help, cause I have no clue how this can be possible.

Comment: You probably just entered the world of KnownTypes.  http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/601224/What-is-KnownType-Attribute-and

Comment: Well it appears to have something to do with it, still have other issues popping up now, but it seems to be a good nudge in the right direction, thanks.